# Getting Records with multiple ids in eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hello i am posting the id of several items along with their quantities to my server eg.:

```
[{"id": "1", "quantity": "2"}, {"id": "2", "quantity": "5"}, {"id": "3", "quanity": "10"}]
```

Now on my server I need to validate each of these ids and get certain values from their respective rows in my database table.

What i simply want to do is this:

```
foreach ($items as $item)
{
  $row = Items::find($item);
  $price = $row->price;
}
```

But here i am wondering if the **foreach loop** will have a huge impact on **speed** and **performance** since the items may be many.

My question is is there a way of doing this in laravel without using a foreach, loop, like a query that can fetch data based on an array of ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to take all the price attributes of certain ids you can use query's builder `whereIn` method to achieve this.`whereIn` accepts an array of values and returns the rows corresponding to these values.It's also very cost efficient when it comes to performance

I see you are passing a json string, so if you where to use `whereIn` one solution might be like the following:

## Example

```
//json string
$json = '[{"id": "1", "quantity": "2"}, {"id": "2", "quantity": "5"}, {"id": "3", "quanity": "10"}]';

//convert json to array
$json_toArray = json_decode($json,true);

//get id values from array
//If you are using php 5.5+ this will work, if you are using an older version you can use 
//array_map method like this: $array_ids = array_map(function ($array) {return $array['id'];}, $json_toArray);
$array_ids = array_column($json_toArray, 'id');

//Finally execute the query

//Using Eloquent
$result = Items::whereIn('id', $array_ids)->select('price')->get();

//Using the Query Builder
$result = DB::table('items')->whereIn('id',$array_ids)->select('price')->get();
```